# php - file download with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

The website I created should be able to let the user upload and download files. When a file is uploaded, the name and the path are stored in a database. To download the file I created a `download.php` where the uploaded files should be listed. The problem I have is that the download page doesn't work, no files are shown and it says that the path wouldn't be defined.

index.php file:

```
<?php
include('db.php');    
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM documents";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);    
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Documents</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="upload.php">Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="download.php">Download</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

        <?php            
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

            $name = $row ['name'];
            $path = $row ['path'];                               
        }      
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php file:

```
<?php
include("db.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];

    if($name){

        $location = "/storage/ssd1/139/2476139/uploads/$name";
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location);
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO documents (name, path) VALUES('$name', '$location')");
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else 
        die("Please select a file.");    
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Browse File:</label>

        <input type="file" name="myfile">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" onclick="index.php">
    </form>

</body>    
</html>
```

download.php file:

```
<?php    
include('db.php');

echo $name."<a href='download.php?dow=$path'>Download</a><br>";

if(isset($_GET['dow'])) {
    $path = $_GET['dow'];
    $res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM documents WHERE path='$path'");

    readfile($path);   
}
?>
```

Comment: You're trying to use the `$path` variable before you define it.

Comment: So may I avoid it when I take the echo part into the if statement?

Comment: Are you sure `$path` is not empty or stored the true path in it ?

Comment: $path is stored into the database and seems to show the correct location

Comment: As other people have pointed out, you're printing `download.php?dow=$path` _before_ you're defining the variable `$path`. Your download.php-file has some weird logic. That's the only place you create 
 link to download.php _with_ a path. It's basically a catch 22 script. It can't print path unless it gets a path, which it then links to itself so it can print the link to itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not put the echo line, which prints the download link, into the script which is used to download the file. How will the user get to this page in the first place?

Instead, put your download link in your main page where you already print the documents something like this:

```
<?php            
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $name = $row ['name'];
    $path = $row ['path'];

    echo '<a href="download.php?dow='.$path.'">'.$name.'</a>';                           
}
?>
```

Then your download.php script will get the path via the `$_GET['dow'];` variable and you can use it, like you already do, in your download.php script.